# Get checkbox value from a specific li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure. I can select the the `<li>` but cannot get the checkbox value - it's `undefined`

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected" style="false">
        <label class="">
            <input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="2447"> 
            <span>England</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('ul li.selected').each(function () {
    console.log('li.selected');
    var val = $(this).closest('label').find('[type=checkbox]').val();
    console.log(val);                                        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the each $(this) is the li-element, so try this:

```
 $('ul li.selected').each(function () {
            console.log("li.selected");
            var val = $(this).find(":checkbox").val();
            console.log(val);                                        
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`closest()` goes up the DOM, you should use `find()` as you want to go down instead. Also note that you can achieve what you require in a single call to `find()`. Try this:

```
$('ul li.selected').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).find('label :checkbox').val();
    console.log(val);                                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this:

```js
 $('li.selected').each(function () {
            console.log("li.selected");
            var val = $(this).find("label").find('input[type=checkbox]').val();
            console.log(val);                                        
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="selected" style="false">
    <label class="">
          <input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="2447"> 
          <span>England</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply search for checkbox : `val = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').val();`

```js
$('ul li.selected').each(function() {
  console.log("li.selected");
  var val = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').val();
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="selected" style="false">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="2447">
      <span>England</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the [input type="checkbox"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) within the `$(this)`:

```js
$('ul li.selected').each(function () {
  console.log('li.selected');
  var val = $(this).find(':checkbox').val();
  console.log(val);                                        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="selected" style="false">
        <label class="">
              <input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="2447"> 
              <span>England</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```